# Create Weblogic Server in Eclipse - Dependency issue

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I'm trying to create a weblogic server in Eclipse. I am selecting 'Oracle WebLogic Server Tools' while selecting the server type. Eclipse is then trying to fetch from repository but fails with this error.

[image: Can't satisfy dependency error]

Eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0)